# Generate Classification Report from Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I generated a confusion matrix via Scikit-Learn's `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)` method. I needed to amend the matrix to drop the last column and last row which I did via `[arr[:-1] for arr in confusion_matrix][:-1]`.

I now need to generate a classification report from the amended matrix, but am not sure how to convert the amended matrix back into `y_true` and `y_pred`. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is not possible, since you are losing information about last label as well as it's related predictions while dropping the last column and last row.

Comment: Yes, but you're stripping out all instances of a particular class, meaning you should be able to get the information from the rest of the classes, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, Let's take binary classification.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = [0,1,1,0,1,1,1]
y_pred = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
a = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

This will produce the output,

> array([[1, 1],
> [3, 2]])

Now when you are amending the matrix using this:

> [arr[:-1] for arr in a][:-1]

You are losing information about last label as well as it's related predictions while dropping the last column and last row

This will produce this output,

> [array([1])]

Now let's take example of 3 classes,

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
y_pred = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,2,2]
a = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 4]])
```

Now when you are amending the matrix:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

Last row and column contains details about all related predictions of **2** which is lost after amendment.

So, it is not possible to convert the amended matrix back into y_true and y_pred.

Comment: I understand that it would not work with binary classification. Why wouldn't it work with multiclass classification?

Comment: @ClaytonC. I added the explanation in the answer, please check it.

Comment: I understand that information is lost, but I believe it is still possible. In your case, there are still 7 total instances that add up correctly both row-wise and column-wise.

Comment: At first i thought it might be possible and I tried ,but how can I get a count of prediction of 2 which was true for 4 times, just from the amended matrix, it really not possible, I tried that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...can you elaborate?

Comment: @ClaytonC. If you are removing both last row and column, that results in complete loss of information in the matrix for last label, and even if you try re-construct the y_pred and y_true, there will be no information related to last label with respect to other predictions, hence it is impossible to re-construct y_pred and y_true just from amended matrix.

Comment: @ClaytonC. In the above answer, "2" was the last label, when the matrix is amended, the prediction of 2 like how many times 2 is truly predicted, how many times 1 is predicted inplace of 2 and how many times 0 is predicted in place of 2 is no more there, thus you cannot reconstruct y_pred and y_true just from the amended matrix.

Comment: Let me phrase this question a different way: forget that I got rid of the last two rows/columns. Is there a programmatic way of getting y_true and y_pred from a confusion matrix.

Comment: @ClaytonC. I would advice you to create a separate question for that.

Comment: @ClaytonC. Does this answer solved your query, if it does, you can mark as answered, otherwise no problem.

Comment: It does not. I created a new question as you recommended.